# Azure SQL DB scaling with API

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Im using a ADF web activity to scale up/down my azure sql db.

Works perfectly with this code:

```
{"sku":{"name":"GP_Gen4_4","tier":"GeneralPurpose"},"location":"West Europe"}
```

However, this doesnt include the azure hybrid benifit saving.

Based on the below link maybe it's something like this

```
{“sku”:
{“name”:”GP_Gen4_4″,”tier”:”GeneralPurpose”}
,”licenseType”:
{“BasePrice”:”SOMETHING_HERE”,”LicenseIncluded “:”SOMETHING_HERE”}
,”location”:”West Europe”
}
```

however I'm not sure the values to put?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/sql/databases/update#databaselicensetype

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi, no it didnt work for me. I receive the following error: {
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "{\"error\":{\"details\":[{\"code\":\"InvalidResourceIdSegment\",\"message\":\"\",\"target\":\"parameters.properties.licenseType\"}],\"code\":\"InvalidResourceIdSegment\",\"message\":\"The 'parameters.properties.licenseType' segment in the url is invalid.\"}}",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Scale up SQLDB"
}

Answer (score 1):

Based on the rest api [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/sql/databases/update#databaselicensetype), the licenseType need to be defined in the `properties` object,not in the `sku` object.

[image]

Refer to the example provided in above link,it should be something like:

```
{
  "sku": {
    "name": "S1",
    "tier": "Standard"
  },
  "properties": {
    "licenseType": {
        "BasePrice":"<>",
        "LicenseIncluded":"<>"
    }
  },
  "location": "southeastasia"
}
```